# Strange behaviou of dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a dict code snippets which is not behaving as expected

```
a = {"d1":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":4},"d2":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":4},"d3":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":4}}
b = {"d1":{"a":1,"b":0},"d2":{"a":0,"c":4},"d3":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":4}}

c = dict.fromkeys(a.keys(),{})
print(c)

for doc in b.keys():
  for word in b[doc].keys():
    c[doc][word] = a[doc][word]*b[doc][word]
print(c)
```

output is:

```
{'d1': {}, 'd2': {}, 'd3': {}}
{'d1': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 16}, 'd2': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 16}, 'd3': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 16}}
```

instead of:

```
{'d1': {}, 'd2': {}, 'd3': {}}
{'d1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 'd2': {'a': 0, 'c': 16}, 'd3': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 16}}
```

I very confused now any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried to trace this code?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you are using a mutable object as the second argument for `fromkeys`.

This is much clearer here:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b'], [])
d['a'].append(1)
print(d)
```

Outputs

```
{'a': [1], 'b': [1]}
```

Comment: Right, depending on the processing order of the dictionary items one can get a whole bunch of weird results, but all three values will always be exactly the same (not just equal).

Comment: I'm not sure how it's related the mutable default arg? It's just that the 2nd arg isn't copied

Comment: @OlvinRoght I've tried to trace the code and I partially traced the problem but now what should I do if I want to have that expected behaviour?

Comment: @Naeem, add `c[doc] = {}` after first loop.

Answer (score 1):

Made a modification to your `for` loop :

```
for doc in b.keys():
  for word in b[doc].keys():
    if doc not in c:
        c[doc]={}
    c[doc][word] = a[doc][word]*b[doc][word]
print(c)

#{'d1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 'd2': {'a': 0, 'c': 16}, 'd3': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 16}}
```

Comment: Or just `c.setdefault(doc, {}).setdefault(word, a[doc][word]*b[doc][word])`, then you don't need the `if doc not in c: c[doc] = {}` part.

Comment: You don't need this condition at all. Just add `c[doc] = {}` after first loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension to create `c` instead:

```
c = {k: {} for k in a.keys()}

for doc in b.keys():
  for word in b[doc].keys():
    c[doc][word] = a[doc][word]*b[doc][word]

print(c)

# {'d1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 'd2': {'a': 0, 'c': 16}, 'd3': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 16}}
```

Notice the difference when you use `fromkeys` vs dictionary comprehension:

```
c = dict.fromkeys(a.keys(),{})
print([id(o) for o in c.values()])

# [53649152, 53649152, 53649152]
# same object reference id!

c = {k: {} for k in a.keys()}
print([id(o) for o in c.values()])

# [53710208, 53649104, 14445232]
# each object has different reference id
```